# Azure: importing not already existing packages in 'src'

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-web-app-service

I have an experiment in which a module R script uses functions defined in a zip source (Data Exploration). [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/) it's described how to do about the packages not already existing in the Azure environment.

[image]

The DataExploration module has been imported from a file Azure.zip containing all the packages and functions I need (as shown in the next picture).

[image]

When I run the experiment nothing goes wrong. At the contrary, watching the log it seems clear that Azure is able to manage the source.

[image]

The problem is that, when I deploy the web service (classic), if I run the experiment I get the following error:

> FailedToEvaluateRScript: The following error occurred during
>   evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in
>   .zip.unpack(pkg, tmpDir) : zip file 'src/scales_0.4.0.zip' not found ,
>   Error code: LibraryExecutionError, Http status code: 400, Timestamp:
>   Thu, 21 Jul 2016 09:05:25 GMT

It's like he cannot see the scales_0.4.0.zip into the 'src' folder.

The strange fact is that all used to work until some days ago. Then I have copied the experiment on a second workspace and it gives me the above error.

I have also tried to upload again the DataExploration module on the new workspace, but it's the same.

Comment: looks like this is an issue and azure ML team is working on it. no fix as yet. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/240d1888-bf53-4f8c-b10c-0b1e862d3168/azure-ml-api-test-failed-because-r-package-zip-file-not-found?forum=MachineLearning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "solved" thanks to the help of the AzureML support: it is a bug they are trying to solve right now.

The bug shows up when you have **more R script modules**, and the **first has no a zip** input module while the following have.

*Workaround*: connect the zip input module to the first R script module too.
[image]